# Scripts fail with error that Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Internal.Strings.dll is unavailable when "Microsoft Service Fabric" is installed

Tags: azure-service-fabric

After upgrading to the latest tools, runtime and SDK (5.5.216.0), PowerShell scripts, such as TestConfiguration.ps1, fail with an error that Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Internal.Strings.dll version 5.0.0.0 can't be found. As soon as I deinstall 'Microsoft Service Fabric' from the control panel, it works just fine. This behavior seems very similar to the Newtonsoft.Json.dll issue that was resolved in 5.5.216.0, just with a different assembly this time around.

Is this a known issue?

It quickly gets tedious to have to uninstall 'Microsoft Service Fabric'  when I run certain scripts and then have to install it again for others that require it.

Example of error:

PS C:\git\sf-admin\DeploymentScripts\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.WindowsServer> .\TestConfiguration.ps1 ..\ClusterConfig.Production.Shared.json
Trace folder doesn't exist. Creating trace folder: C:\git\sf-admin\DeploymentScripts\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.WindowsServer\DeploymentTraces
Running Best Practices Analyzer...
Standalone package dependent files not found. Check package structure. Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Internal.Strings, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or on
e of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Internal.Strings, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.ClusterManagementCommon.ValidatorExtensions.ThrowValidationExceptionIfNull[T](T parameter, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.BPA.BestPracticesAnalyzer.IsJsonConfigModelValid(StandAloneInstallerJsonModelBase config)

Thanks,
Hans

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're getting that error due to the SDK/Runtime installing dll's to the GAC which are being picked up.

Try running moving your Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.WindowsServer folder to another machine and running TestConfiguration.ps1 again.

If you're running the scripts from a box without internet access then you'll need to specify the location of the .cab which contains the runtime

```
-FabricRuntimePackagePath C:\temp\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.WindowsServer.5.5.216.0\MicrosoftAzureServiceFabric5.5.216.0.cab
```

Comment: Thanks, fenneh. Yes, running it on another machine works, but my point is that it's pretty bad that I have to run certain scripts on a machine without  'Microsoft Service Fabric' while some work with it installed. We want to have one deployment machine for all SF related scripts. I'll have to try the now latest version to see if it's been addressed.

Comment: Not disagreeing with you at all. In your scenario, your "Deployment Machine" shouldn't have Service Fabric installed on it. I believe it just needs the SDK and it'd be that machine which runs your scripts.

Personally I was under the impression the scripts needed to be ran on each box with service fabric on, this wasn't the case.